# how to load sub category based on category by calling jquery function from <td> of javascript function for adding rows dynamically?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

When I am clicking the add row button the category dropdown list loads successfully, but when I'm selecting an option from this category list the sub category does not load any list.

The Javascript function for adding rows dynamically:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var i=1;
        $("#add_row").click(function(){
            $('#addr'+i).html("<td>"+ (i+1) +"</td>   <td><select name='parent_catt"+i+"' id='parent_catt' class='form-control input-md'><?php while($row2 = $query2_parent->fetch_array()): ?><option value='<?php echo $row2["cat_id"]; ?>'><?php echo $row2["category"]; ?></option><?php endwhile; ?></select></td><td><select name='sub_catt"+i+"' id='sub_catt' class='form-control input-md'></select></td><td><input  name='mobile"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='Mobile'  class='form-control input-md'></td><td><input  name='mobile"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='Mobile'  class='form-control input-md'></td><td><input  name='mobile"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='Mobile'  class='form-control input-md'></td>");

            $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr'+(i+1)+'"></tr>');
            i++; 
        });

        $("#delete_row").click(function(){
            if(i>1){
                $("#addr"+(i-1)).html('');
                i--;
            }
        });

    });                     
</script>
```

jQuery function to load subcategory:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#parent_catt").click(function() {
        alert("clicked");
        $(this).after('<div id="loader"><img src="images/loading.gif" alt="loading subcategory" /></div>');
        $.get('loadsubcat.php?parent_catt=' + $(this).val(), function(data) {
            $('#sub_catt').html(data);
            $('#loader').slideUp(200, function() {
                $(this).remove();
            });
        }); 
    });

});
</script>
```

PHP code for fetch detail:

```
<?php 
include('dbconnect.php');


$parent_catt = $_GET['parent_catt'];

$query2 = $con->query("SELECT * FROM subcategory WHERE cat_id = '$parent_catt'");
while($row2 = $query2->fetch_array()) {
    echo "<option value='$row2[subcat_id]'>$row2[subcategory]</option>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this line

```
$("#parent_catt").click(function() {
```

by this

```
$(document).off("click", "#parent_catt").on("click", "#parent_catt", function(){
```

Comment: thanks man. the second row works fine with loading subcategory by replacing this code but when im adding 3rd row the category changes of 3rd row affects subcategory changes of 2nd row and so on...

Answer (score 0):

use JQuery.on function

```
$( "#parent_catt" ).on( "click", function() {
   alert("clicked");
});
```